# How to call aspecific function in vbscript from VB.net code

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, interop

From VB.net we can execute VBScript code by using following line:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.start("AbsolutePathofVBScriptfile")
```

But how can one call a specific function present in vbscript from VB.net code? 
I searched for that but couldn't figure it out. Some things I found were IActiveScript, MSScript.ocx...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that this can be done, as you are operating in two totally different domains.

That line of code you present does nothing different than if you double-clicked the vbscript file.

I've done next to no vbscript programming, but what about this... Create another script file (stub) that does nothing but call a function (subroutine) in your main, library file. Then, invoke the stub from the VB.net application.

**library.vbs**

```
Function LibraryFunction(oValue)
    Wscript.Echo "LibraryRoutine Running!"
End Sub

...
```

**stub.vbs**

```
' Essentially "Import" the library script
Const ForReading = 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("procedures.vbs", ForReading)
Execute objFile.ReadAll()

' Call the appropriate function from library
LibraryFunction(4)
```

**VB.net**

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.start("stub.vbs")
```

[Functions, Subroutines, and How to Call Them From Other Scripts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176984.aspx)